# How to use shake.js on Intel XDK?

Tags: javascript, shake, intel-xdk

I'am trying to use the `shake.js` [library from alex gibson](https://github.com/alexgibson/shake.js/) on my HTML5 Hybrid apps.

I followed the github instruction but it doesn't work.

I put this to  at the head of my `index.html`

```
<script src="themes/js/shake.js"> </script>
<script>

  window.addEventListener('shake', shakeEventDidOccur, false);

  function shakeEventDidOccur () {

    alert('shaking');
  };

</script>
```

i'm sure i'm forgetting something. Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: Can see that `shake.js` loaded in browser console?

Comment: How to do this pleas ? i'am not used to the JS console

Comment: You could see it in Chrome console.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this library, but I recommend that you do not attach the event until after the device ready event has been detected.

Comment: The script is loaded , and i put if after the device ready event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Shake.js` uses HTML5 `devicemotion` event to trigger shake event, it will work if device supports the feature, your code worked on iPhone5 with app built with Intel XDK and in Intel XDK's App Preview.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>XDK</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0;" />
    <style>
        body {font-family:arial;background-color:white}
    </style>  
    <script src="shake.js"> </script>
    <script>
      window.addEventListener('shake', shakeEventDidOccur, false);
      function shakeEventDidOccur () {
        alert('shaking');
      };
    </script>
</head>
<body> 
<h1>Shake.js Demo</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks , but same for me , still not working on emulator or in app preview

Comment: @AurélienPigotBennour which device are you using?

Comment: Sorry my bad , it's working on my device, it's just not working on the XDK emulator.

Comment: That's because the emulator is actually a desktop browser that's been augmented to support the Cordova and XDK apis, but it hasn't been augmented for the standard HTML5 apis that one might find in a mobile browser (I know sounds upside down). You should find those APIs implemented in the Debug tab, which works as well (or better) than the emulator tab, just a somewhat slower turnaround time compared to the emulator.